# Swift 3 - Trigger pushViewController from other viewcontroller

Tags: swift, triggers, uinavigationcontroller, viewcontroller, uisplitviewcontroller

currently i am in my custom split view controller which extends from UISplitViewController and i want to trigger a pushViewController in the master viewcontroller of it:

```
(self.splitViewController?.viewControllers.first as! MasterViewController).navigationController?.pushViewController(viewControllerObject, animated: true)
```

But my app just crashes.. could anybody help me out?

Thanks and Greetings!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well I believe it's just a syntax issue. The first view controller of your split view controller is probably just the navigation controller.

```
(self.splitViewController?.viewControllers.first as! UINavigationController).pushViewController(viewControllerObject, animated: true)
```

Should work.